# NodeJs: Is there a way to exit the whole function instead of just the internal function with return?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sqlite, express

So I have this function

```
app.post('/assignment/loan', (req, res) => {
```

And inside that function I have this function

```
db.run('SELECT loanable FROM book WHERE id=?',[bookID],(err,row)=>{
```

I use return but it only exits the internal function and keeps on going with the rest. I want to stop the whole post function from executing further. Is there a way to do that?

Edit: Full code here: https://pastebin.com/8TPThfpW

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I feel like there's information missing. Can you post your entire code? Also what do you mean by "return"? Do you want your server to respond with a value/error ?

Comment: Re *"Edit: Full code here: https://pastebin.com/8TPThfpW"* The way SO works, your whole question (including any necessary code) has to be **in** your question, not just linked. Three reasons: People shouldn't have to go off-site to help you; some sites are blocked for some users; and links rot, making the question and its answers useless to people in the future. Please put a [mcve] (note the **minimal**! :-) ) **in** the question. More: [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I apologize for the poor presentation of my question. Your answer however is helpful and was something I was trying that I couldnt get to work for some reason. I will try it again Thank you sir!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not directly. By the time your `run` callback is running, the function that called it has *already returned*. This is because of the nature of JavaScript's run-to-completion semantics and the fact that Node.js callbacks of this kind are called asynchronously.

You might consider using promise wrappers around those functions, and then putting your logic in an `async` function so that you can make the function's logic wait until the `run` operation and your handling of its results are complete. It's hard to give you a concrete suggestion with such fragmentary code to work from, but something *vaguely* like this:

```
// In an `async` function...
const res = await promiseEnabledAppPost('/assignment/loan');
const row = await promiseEnabledDBRun('SELECT loanable FROM book WHERE id=?',[bookID]);
// ...do something with `row`...
if (/* you don't want to continue with the `post` callback logic */ {
    return;
}
// ...continue the logic from the `post` callback...
```